# Dumpsys Battery History Tags

Tags: android, android-source, battery, dumpsys

I am studying battery profiling with batterystats logs and there is a section called "Battery History" with a bunch of informations.

[image]

Is there a list with all tags that can appear on it? (ex: "job=", "screen", "audio", "running" etc)
I could not find in official document nor in source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official document about the tags. And it can be seen in [BatteryStats.HISTORY_STATE_DESCRIPTIONS](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/BatteryStats.java;l=2477?q=HISTORY_STATE_DESCRIPTIONS)

There are some documents about the tools "Battery Historian"
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/setup-battery-historian
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/battery-historian